# Python sqlite - quotes usage in execute() method

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

While reading through [python sqlite3 DB-API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#), the first example of creating table uses thee single quotes:

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
             (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')
```

But in other examples there are double quotes:

```
cur.execute("create table people (name_last, age)")
```

So I've got 2 questions:

1. It this really any difference? How can it affect `create table` command?
2. Which one is better to use with parameters? ex.:

   `c.execute('''CREATE TABLE %s(date text, trans text, symbol text, qty
   real, price real)''' % table_name)`

VS.

```
 cur.execute("create table %s (name_last, age)" % table_name)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Is this really any difference? How can it affect create table command?
```

Using single/double quoted string or a triple-quoted string doesn't affect the create command in any way.  They are ultimately just string arguments to the create command.

```
Which one is better to use with parameters?
```

Double quotes are the norm in most of the python programs.  Triple quotes are used mostly when you have a big multi-line string copy-pasted from somewhere else and you want to embed them in your program.  In the link that you gave above, [we can see one such example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executescript) in the usage in cursor.executescript(), where an sql script (which probably existed before) is used within the program.

Answer (score 3):

There is basically no rule for double or single quotes.

But three consecutive quotes start multiline quoted values.

Answer (score 1):

using three `"""` is like commenting out a line

```
#this text python doesn't read so you can write about your code

"""it allows
you to type
over multiple
lines."""
```

Also you can use `"` or `'` python see them both the same as long as you close with the same style.

Comment: Three quotes can also be used for multiline comments. But you cannot say three quotes is always a comment!

Comment: @Warmee Just for the record, these are docstrings. They aren't exactly comments, they are used when the documentation is created automatically. I'd refrain from even suggesting their usage as comments.